# Angle between $(X,Y)$ and $(E(X), E(Y)) $ where X and Y are independent random variables.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables with known (different/same) probability distribution functions. Now consider the vector $(X,Y)$, I want to find the angle between $(X,Y)$ and $(E(X), E(Y))$. I am guessing that again the angle should be a random variable, but I don't know how to find its PDF. In addition, suppose that $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ are not zero at the same time. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: What if E(X)=E(Y)=0?

Comment: I edited the question, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are interested in the angle it makes with $(E(X),E(Y))$, because you can just find out the angle it makes with the $x$-axis and subtract the angle $(E(X),E(Y))$ makes from $x$-axis from this.

More formally:

Let $t \in [0,2\pi)$ be the angle $(E(X),E(Y))$ makes with the $x$-axis. (it equals to $\arctan(E(Y)/E(X))+2\pi k$ for some $k$ depending on which quadrant you are in).

Let $\Theta$ denote the angle $(X,Y)$ makes with the $x$-axis and let $f$ and $g$ be the density of $X$ and $Y$ respectively, then

Making a polar coordinate transformation:

Let $x=r\sin \theta $ and $y=r\cos \theta$, with $r\in[0,\infty),\theta\in[0,2\pi)$, then the Jacobian of the transformation is $r$.

$$P(\theta_1<\Theta<\theta_2)=\int^{\theta_2}_{\theta_1}\int^\infty_0f(r\sin\theta)g(r\cos\theta)r\text{d}r\text{d}\theta$$

so the density of $\Theta$ is given by

$$h(\theta)=\int^\infty_0f(r\sin\theta)g(r\cos\theta)r\text{d}r$$.

Now the angle you want is just $u=t-\theta$, so

$$\tilde{h}(u) = \int^\infty_0f(r\sin(t-u))g(r\cos(t-u))\text{d}r$$

Added: in fact you could have done this even if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, just replace $f(x)g(y)$ with $f(x,y)$ where $f$ is the joint distribution.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I just need the angle it makes with the x-axis.

Comment: How can I generalize it for more than 2 random variables?

Comment: @Alex how do you define angle with, say 3, variables?

Comment: the angle would be between (X,Y,Z) and (E(x),E(y),E(Z))